# does .map() return once per iteration or once after all iterations are complete?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn the mechanics behind the `.map()` method.

**Question 1)** In the test code below the first statement inside `.map()` is `let output = [];`.  Is output reset to an empty array at the beginning of each iteration?

**Question 2)** The last statement in `.map()` is `return output;`  Does `.map()` return an output value at the end of each iteration (in this case 3 returns) or does it store up the output from all of the iterations and return a new, completed array after all of the iterations are done?

Thanks so much for any help!

```js
"use strict";
 
var creatureArray, updatedCreatureArray;
 
creatureArray = [
  ['zombie', 30, 1, 'bite', 0, 5],
  ['skeleton', 10, 2, 'sword', 1, 10],
  ['orc', 15, 4, 'club', 1, 7]
];

updatedCreatureArray = creatureArray
  .map((value) => {
    let output = [];
    output = ['species'].concat(value);
    output[6] += 100;
    return output;
});

console.log(updatedCreatureArray);
```

Comment: **1)** `output` is not really "_reset_" on each iteration. It is a new variable that is created each time, in the scope of your function in that iteration. **2)** `.map()` does not return every single value, your function already does that. `.map()` just takes care of gathering each value you return to it, stores it in an Array, and returns that Array.

Comment: `array.map(f)` means: apply the function `f` on each and every item of the array. The `return` is a return from `f` not from `map`. `f` is called `array.length` times and the accumulated results of all these calls is what `map` returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question 1)** In the test code below the first statement inside `.map()` is `let output = [];`. Is output reset to an empty array at the beginning of each iteration?

The function passed to `.map()` declares `output` as a local variable, so its value won't be shared between iterations. It will always start out as an empty array and then go out of scope when that iteration is over.

> **Question 2)** The last statement in `.map()` is `return output;` Does `.map()` return an output value at the end of each iteration (in this case 3 returns) or does it store up the output from all of the iterations and return a new, completed array after all of the iterations are done?

A function can only return once if it's called once, and `.map()` is no exception. It won't return until all of the iterations have completed. The return value of `.map()` is an array of all the return values that came from executing the function parameter with each element in the original array.

Perhaps this would be clearer if you saw how `.map()` can be implemented:

```
Array.prototype.map = function(callback) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    result[i] = callback(this[i], i, this);
  }
  return result;
};
```

<sub>(This implementation is a simplification. The [real `Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) has some other features also.)</sub>

Comment: Very intriguing.  But how does `.map()` return all of the values with `return result;` when `result = [];`  clears result at the beginning of each iteration?  Shouldn't it only return the final iteration?  Everything before that last iteration was already vaporized.

Comment: @DR01D `result = []` isn't inside the `for` loop. It only gets initialized once (indeed, a `const` variable *can't* be reinitialized).

Comment: You are right, `const` is outside the loop and that makes sense. 
 But in my version I used `let` which reset each cycle and it still worked fine.  How is that possible if `return` is only fires once at the end?

Comment: you did it correctly with `const` but I did it with `let` and it still worked.  But how is that possible?  If it is resetting each iteration shouldn't it only return the last cycle?

Comment: @DR01D Your `let` statement is inside of the function which is here referred to as `callback`. It's being executed many times inside the `for` loop, and the return values are deposited into `result`, each at a different index.

Comment: Ok so my `let` statement is inside of the `callback` argument which is a function?  Am I making headway yet?

Comment: @DR01D Yes! I think you're getting it. `callback` is a function. In JavaScript, functions are regular values just like strings, arrays, and numbers. They can be passed as parameters to functions, returned from functions, stored in arrays, etc.

Comment: I feel like I learned something but somehow actually know less.  haha

Comment: 4castle where did you get the official `.map()` code? I learn a lot more when I can tear something down to the basics.

Comment: @DR01D The "official" `.map()` code is probably written in C++, not JavaScript. It comes built-in with modern browsers. You can see a more accurate JavaScript implementation though [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill).

Comment: if that's not the official code how do you know it's correct?  Where is the missing handbook to learn these kinds of basic mechanics?

Comment: BTW I love Mozilla.  Best JS site ever.

Comment: It's not anything I learned from a book. I've just used `.map()` a lot, and the implementation I've given is sufficient for the great majority of use cases.

Comment: 4castle if I take one foundational piece of information away from this can it be that a function can only execute its return once?  No ifs, ands or buts.   One time only.

Comment: @DR01D Right, a function can only return once. It only appears that `.map()` returns more than once because it's actually the `callback` function being called multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah output is set to an empty array at the beginning of each iteration and the return value defines the new value of the current element.

Comment: Awesome!  Knowing the mechanics helps so much when you're trying to do bigger things.